# How to remove from these 2 lists of lists the possible lists that appear in both lists of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, typeerror

These are the two lists, both of which have the same number of elements:

```py
list1 = [['23', '30', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'pm'], ['1', '', 'pm'], ['5', '', 'pm']]

list2 = [['23', '30', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['05', '00', 'pm']]
```

I try with this:

```py
list1 = list(list1 - list2)
list2 = list(list2 - list1)

print(repr(list1))
print(repr(list2))
```

but I get this **error** when trying to subtract the elements that are the same in both lists

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I need the lists to be like this, that is, within each of them there are only those elements that are different:

```py
list1 = [['1', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'pm'], ['1', '', 'pm'], ['5', '', 'pm']]

list2 = [['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['05', '00', 'pm']]
```

How could I achieve this? (**if possible without using additional libraries**, although if there is no other way I would have no problem using them)

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: Whoo you can see my code even before I write it :p

Comment: How is `['01', '00', 'am']` in your second `list2`? `['01', '00', 'am']` is in both lists

Comment: @MichaelS. The objective is to leave the lists of lists, only with those lists that are exclusive to each one of them, for example, the list `['01', '00', 'am']` is one of those that should be removed because it appears in both lists of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `zip` to iterate the lists in parallel, and another `zip` to separate the output back in two lists:

```
l1,l2 = map(list, zip(*((a,b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2) if a!=b)))
```

Output:

```
# l1
[['1', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'pm'], ['1', '', 'pm'], ['5', '', 'pm']]

# l2
[['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['05', '00', 'pm']]
```

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct answer, I think OP needed to clarify that they also wanted to take into account the position of the lists within the lists to be counted as duplicates, but I suppose their desired output alluded to that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two lists are paired correctly, you could use a zip in a list comprehension.

```
[[i,j] for i,j in zip(list1,list2) if i!=j]
```